# autoSizeColumn POI Java is not working properly

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am using POI 3.9 & jdk1.6.0_14.

I am using the below code to autoSizeColumn, but the issue is when the excel is generated, its not completely autosized to column, when i double click on between columns, at that time i can see that column in autosized correctly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            HSSFSheet thisSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
            log.info("Last row : "+thisSheet.getLastRowNum());
            HSSFRow rowexcel = thisSheet.getRow(thisSheet.getLastRowNum());
            // Auto sizing columns
            for (short j = 0; j < rowexcel.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
                workbook.getSheetAt(i).autoSizeColumn(j);
            }
            // Freezing the top row
            workbook.getSheetAt(i).createFreezePane(0, 1);
        }
```

Instead of

```
HSSFRow rowexcel = thisSheet.getRow(thisSheet.getLastRowNum());
```

I have also tried with top row

```
HSSFRow rowexcel = thisSheet.getRow(0);
```

But still no resolution.

Comment: Do you have all the fonts you use present + available to Java on the system you're generating the file on?

Comment: Yes its using Arial font, which is present in Windows/Font. The generated file has Arial font too.

Comment: Does Java see it though? The column sizing is very font dependent, and if Java doesn't have access to the right font it can't properly calculate the width...

Comment: U can also use setColumnWidth for each header cells.So it will apply size for all the cells.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the exact issue you described and was able to find some success by explicitly setting the font via the `Cell` style as suggested in some of the comments above (also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943493/apache-poi-autosizecolumn-resizes-incorrectly)).

However, one thing I noticed is that `autoSizeColumn` was still not taking into consideration the width of all cells.  Particularly, I have a row of cells that are basically the column headers describing each column's data.  These cells had the custom `Font` applied successfully, but were still not being considered with respect to the column's width when `autoSizeColumn` ran.  There are differences, but I would have assumed they were irrelevant.  For example, the headers had a different cell type from the rest of the data in the column... and the cell headers have different colors applied to make them stand out.

Having said that, try creating a sheet with just a very basic set of cell styles applied, and then try tweaking from there:

```
// Let's test with Arial, 10pt
Font testFont = workbook.createFont();
testFont.setFontName("Arial");
testFont.setFontHeightInPoints((short)10);

// We'll apply a very bare-bones style to our cells that just applies the Font
CellStyle testCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
testCellStyle.setFont(testFont);

// Your real data cell creation would go here instead of my dummy code:
CreationHelper creationHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
Row testRow = thisSheet.createRow(0);
int currentColumn = 0;

Cell testCell = testRow.createCell(currentColumn++);
testCell.setCellStyle(testCellStyle);
testCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
testCell.setCellValue(creationHelper.createRichTextString("Cell Data Goes Here");

testCell = testRow.createCell(currentColumn++);
testCell.setCellStyle(testCellStyle);
testCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
testCell.setCellValue(creationHelper.createRichTextString("Your Real Code Won't Be This Redundant :)");
```

One final thought, if `autoSizeColumn` is still doing unfortunate or inconsistent things to column widths, you could add a safety net to ensure that columns don't get smaller than the default:

```
int origColWidth = thisSheet.getColumnWidth(currentColumn);
thisSheet.autoSizeColumn(currentColumn);

// Reset to original width if resized width is smaller than default/original
if (origColWidth > thisSheet.getColumnWidth(currentColumn))
  thisSheet.setColumnWidth(currentColumn, origColWidth);
```